# How to handle situation of loading wrong shared library version

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, embedded-linux

I am facing with strange situation. My engine is supposed to call some function of another library. Problems is if I can have wrong (incompatible) library package version in the system, engine will stop working without any exception or Linux signal. Basically, engine is handling basic Linux signals as segmentation fault etc. These signals will not come. My program is looking like:

```
try {
    interface->somefunctioncall(...);
} catch(...) {
    ;
}
```

interface->somefunctioncall(...) is call to another shared library from another package. If package has wrong version, this call will cause to crash engine and there will be no information in Linux system about it. I want only to handle this situation somehow and store some information to the log. Whatever will happen. Engine can crash. But I want to have stored information in log why engine crashed.
Another nice hint could be, if I can handle this situation in run time and engine could continue.
Make sure that I am developing on embedded Linux with limited possibilities to use third - parties software. 
Please no hints like:

```
if (packageversion != expectedversion) {
    do_not_do_call_and_log_the_problem();
} else {
    interface->somefunctioncall(...);
}
```

Thanks a lot for hints. :-)

Comment: *Why* wouldn't solutions along the lines of `if (packageversion != expectedversion) {` be acceptable? - seems like the obvious solution..

Comment: Make sure to link to the version of the library you need, including the major and minor version numbers. (Generally the third number, if there is one, is for bugfixes that do not break compatibility.) You might possibly even need to include a copy yourself as part of your application, but if it’s available from a package manager, you should just be able to list the specific version as a dependency.

Comment: Or can you link that library statically?

Comment: Solution if (packageversion != expectedversion) is not acceptable for me, because I have 1.000.000 builds and 1.000.000 versions of packages. Everyone in the project can change something in any library and there is no way to watch and handle all these changes.

Comment: I cannot link it statically, because I am not the owner of the package. I do not have any control on the package and project. This is not good solution. I will get lots of build problems.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see what the CPU is doing? If it's pegged at 100% that probably means you're in an infinite loop, which would explain the lack of crash. *If it is an infinite loop*, one thing you could do is set an alarm before making the call and cancel it afterwards.

```
alarm( 5 ); // 5 seconds, make it long enough to be certain that somefunctioncall should have returned
interface->somefunctioncall(...);
alarm( 0 ); // to cancel the alarm
```

Then wherever you're handling signals in your code, handle the `SIGALRM` signal. If you receive `SIGALRM` the "protected" call is probably in an infinite loop and you can abort the program, after logging whatever you want.

I should add that this really isn't an *optimal* solution unless you really have no administrative control over package versions on your system. This is *a* solution to a problem that really *ought* to be solved elsewhere.

One concrete reason this is not optimal is that it creates a potential race condition. This can be mitigated by making the alarm time much longer than the call should take. Nevertheless, this creates new potential problems (and complicates your code) for the sake of "fixing" other problems that *should* be fixed elsewhere.

Comment: If I will call a function interface->somefunctioncall(...) from wrong package CPU is 0%, Linux closes engine and nothing is done. Program does not continue and nothing after interface->somefunctioncall(...) is executed. Simple, engine is done as killed but without signal.

Comment: It could be one bad solution to execute interface calls in another process and check for results of process. But, that will be very slow for me. If I would have DBus or COM or something else. I could ping interface, I would check for results... There is nice handling of these problems. Unfortunately, I supposed to do direct calls to libraries.